# Laravel Array to string conversion when using sizeof

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

i'm new on laravel, basically when i using codeigniter this code works fine.
The problem is i cannot use this for insert data.

```
for($count = 0; $count < sizeof($cid); $count++){
inset to table for item 1,
inset to table for item 2, 
inset to table for item 3,
}
```

this is my controller

```
   $request->validate([
        'pembelian_kode' => 'required',
        'barang_kode' => 'required',
        'pembelian_total' => 'required',
        'pembelian_qty' => 'required',
        'supplier_id' => 'required',
      ]);

      $cid = Input::POST('cid');
      $cg = PembelianModel::create($request->all());

      if($cg){
        for($count = 0; $count < sizeof($cid); $count++){
          DB::table('pembelian_details')->insert([
            'pembelian_kode' => $request['pembelian_kode'], 'barang_kode' => $request['barang_kode'], 'pd_qty' => $request['pembelian_qty']]
          );
        }
      }
      return redirect()->route('pembelians.index')
      ->with('success','Data berhasil ditambah');

reults error 
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `pembelian_details` (`pembelian_kode`, `barang_kode`, `pd_qty`) values (PBL1812025877, BRG10181125230, 10))
```

so i have two tables 1 is 'orders' and also 'order_details'. For the table orders it has been successful in adding data, but for orders details there are still errors.

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

**I just modified your script .Hope this will work**

**Problems:**

```
$request['barang_kode']
```

- Missing index
- $request is an object not array

  ```
       $cid = $request->cid;
          $cg = PembelianModel::create($request->all());

          if($cg){
              for($count = 0; $count < count($cid); $count++){
                  DB::table('pembelian_details')->insert([
                          'pembelian_kode' => $request->pembelian_kode[$count],
                          'barang_kode' => $request->barang_kode[$count],
                          'pd_qty' => $request->pembelian_qty[$count]
                      ]
                  );
              }
          }
          return redirect()->route('pembelians.index')
              ->with('success','Data berhasil ditambah');
  ```